# Handling websocket clients across multiple processes

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I have a well working websocket implementation using python's tornado framework, used as a backend, working well on single tornado processes. Although I am trying, I cannot reserve websocket client connections between multiple processes.

I am currently adding client instances to a module's dictionary object, which is not easily accessible from other processes.

How should someone preserve a class instance between multiple processes in python (more specifically, tornado)?

Comment: This is normal. Processes isolate resources from each other. There exists several different inter-process communication systems (IPC) that will allow you to pass messages between n processes.
Why do you want to preserve a socket connection between multiple processes? This would only lead to errors / synchronization issues (two processes writing/reading at the same time).

Comment: The reason I want to run multiple processes is because one morning we found out that socket has frozen and I had to restart the process in order to get it working. So service stability was the idea. :) And the reason I need to preserver connection between processes is that we need to send messages from one connected client to another.

Comment: Don't share objects between processes, you would need to make them thread-safe. Sounds like what you're trying to accomplish should be handled by another layer (message queue, database ...) and gracefully handling frozen sockets.

Comment: does this have to be Tornado? wouldnt nodejs do? I have a solution if this is in node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to share objects between processes. Just don't do it.

If your use case is that one process stopped for any reason, have the client handle the closure by reconnecting. The connection will be routed to another, running Tornado process.

If your use case is to share a message with other Tornado processes, have a think about your network topology: You might send the message to a new parent node that distributes the message back to all Tornado instances (including the original Tornado process).

The [ZMQ](http://zeromq.org/) library and documentation are wonderful resources and will give you some ideas.